# MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance gives wrong results on iphoneX

Tags: swift, mapkit, iphone-x

When setting the region for a MKMapView using MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance, the resulting region always gives the wrong results, where the size is always slightly bigger than the best fit I would get for other phone models.

for example, doing:

```
let region         = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(someLocation, 400, 200)
let adjustedRegion = mapView.regionThatFits(region)
mapView.setRegion(adjustedRegion, animated: true)
```

(The mapview's vertical and horizontal ratios are defined to be set to 2:1)

would always result in a view that would give me 420 m vertically, 210~ m horizontally, while this doesn't happen for other phone models.

Understandably, it is meant to find the 'best fit` region for the specified dimensions, what's concerning me is that the results are different on iPhone X specifically. (on models 8, 8+, 5s)

Is there something I need to do specifically for iPhone X models with mapViews?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, mapkit's mapView's MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance does it's calculations without the safe area insets.

Since my mapView was set to be at the bottom of the screen, when applying the vertical distance, some reduction needs to be made to compensate for this weird behaviour.

```
let verticalDistance = 400 * ((mapView.bounds.height - mapView.safeAreaInsets.bottom) / mapView.bounds.height )
let region         = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(someLocation, verticalDistance, 200)
let adjustedRegion = mapView.regionThatFits(region)
mapView.setRegion(adjustedRegion, animated: true)
```

This allow the mapView's resulting region to be correct in vertical and horizontal distance (compared against google map's web distance measuring tool)